# Implementing a hash combiner in Swift

Tags: swift, hash

I'm extending a `struct` conform to `Hashable`. I'll use the [DJB2](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) hash combiner to accomplish this.

To make it easy to write hash function for other things, I'd like to extend the `Hashable` protocol so that my hash function can be written like this:

```
extension MyStruct: Hashable {
  public var hashValue: Int {
    return property1.combineHash(with: property2).combineHash(with: property3)
  }
}
```

But when I try to write the extension to `Hashable` that implements `combineHash(with:), like this:

```
extension Hashable {
  func combineHash(with hashableOther:Hashable) -> Int {
    let ownHash = self.hashValue
    let otherHash = hashableOther.hashValue
    return (ownHash << 5) &+ ownHash &+ otherHash
  }
}
```

… then I get this compilation error:

> /Users/benjohn/Code/Nice/nice/nice/CombineHash.swift:12:43: Protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Is this something that Swift won't let me do, or am I just doing it wrong and getting an unhelpful error message?

---

**Aside** A comment from JAL links to [a code review of a swift hash function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148763/extending-cgpoint-to-conform-to-hashable) that is also written by Martin who provides the accepted answer below! He mentions a different hash combiner in that discussion, which is based on one in the c++ boost library. The discussion really is worth reading. The alternative combiner has fewer collisions (on the data tested).

Comment: [Related on Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/148763/73433)

Comment: @JAL Nice one – useful info in there! Particularly the point that Swift's hash value type is a signed int, so my code would perform poorly as given here!

Comment: Yes, I had a similar issue.  Martin's Swift translation of the Boost hash combine function is a great function to have in your toolbox.

Comment: @Benjohn: Only right-shifts of signed integers preserve the sign bit. Your left-shifts are unproblematic.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, okay, my original hash isn't that bad? :-) I hadn't noticed until now that you also wrote the code review regarding the hash that Jal linked to! The two of you are like a hash-crime fighting duo, preventing collisions and maintaining big O expectations – I thank you for it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot define a parameter of type `P` if `P`
is a protocol which has `Self` or associated type requirements.
In this case it is the `Equatable` protocol from which `Hashable`
inherits, which has a `Self` requirement:

```
public static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

What you can do is to define a generic method instead:

```
extension Hashable {
    func combineHash<T: Hashable>(with hashableOther: T) -> Int {
        let ownHash = self.hashValue
        let otherHash = hashableOther.hashValue
        return (ownHash << 5) &+ ownHash &+ otherHash
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Use the method `hash(into:)` from the Apple Developer Documentation:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable

```
struct GridPoint {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}

extension GridPoint: Hashable {

    static func == (lhs: GridPoint, rhs: GridPoint) -> Bool {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(x)
        hasher.combine(y)
    }

}
```